# How to iterate through duplicate keys in an object

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

When i type this in my console:

```
var a = {"baz":null, "baz":null, "baz":null, "taz":null};

for (var x in a) {
   console.log(x);
}
```

I only get:
"baz"
"taz"

I need to capture all instances of the key "baz"... is there any way to do this? for...in will only do the above.

Comment: You cannot duplicate keys, they must be unique.

Comment: You cannot have the same key twice. That'd negate the point of a key. How would that work?!

Comment: You are redefining `baz` each time you declare it inside the `a` object.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to capture all instances of the key "baz"... is there any way to do this?

No there is not. The resulting object won't contain information about duplicate keys in any way.

Depending on your use case, you can either use an array instead of an object, or use an array as value of the property (and process it accordingly):

```
var a = {"baz": [null, null, null], "taz":null};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by having an array as the value for your key:

```
{baz: ["homer","bart","liza"], foo:[1,2,3] }
```

Then to display:

```
for (var x in a) {

  for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
  console.log(a[i]);
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Felix pointed out, you cannot have duplicate keys.
An alternate way to structure your data may be an Array of dicts.

(I assume that you were trying to store data with each key, 'null' in your question. I represent that with the "other_value" key)

```
var a = [{name : "baz", other_value : null}, {name : "baz", other_value : null}, {name : "taz", other_value : null}];

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    console.log(a[i].name);
}
```